# How can i send a checkbox value to Email

Tags: android, android-checkbox

i am from Germany (please excuse my broken english) and i have a Question about Android Studio programming. I want my App to act as follows: If a user click on a Checkbox the Name of the checkbox should send to an email. I get it worked but i only get "True" or "False" in my email Text. I want not True or False i want the checkbox Name (label.android:text in the Email)!

MAIN ACTIVITY.java:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    String str="";
    if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {

         str =checkBox1.getText().toString()+"TEST";

    } else {

         checkBox1.setEnabled(false);
         emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "+ "\n Fehler: " + checkBox1.getText().toString();

    }
}
```

XML:

```
 <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:text="@string/Checkbox1"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"/>
```

Comment: Then use `getText` instead of `isSelected`? Or add your code to your question using the edit link between the comments here and your question

Comment: Controll if the CheckBox is checked.
If it's true you can return all strings that you want.

Comment: could you please show an example using my posted code ??

Comment: Explain better what do you want.
The onClick method is from a Button or to CheckBox?
Because if you have a button, when it's pressed you must check your CheckBox (if cheked or not?).
Or it's a listener in the CheckBox? (if the user check the box send email immediately)

Answer (score 0):

What i think you should do is add a listener on your checkbox like

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
  // Here if the checkBox is checked you can set Email text
     if(isChecked){
        txt.setText("Whatever text you want.");
      }

   }
```

}
);
if your requirement is still not matched try posting your code.

Okay try this

XML:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
    android:text="@string/Checkbox1"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"/>
```

Java Code:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
  // Here if the checkBox is checked you can set Email text
     if(isChecked){
        String str = "Name of checkbox TEST";
      }
     else{
       checkBox.setEnabled(false);
     }

   }
} );
```

Comment: OK sorry my explanation was not accurate enough and I try it again. When a User chlick the checkbox, and send the mail i get following Text in my email "Schelchtes Druckbild:true". If the Checkbox was not clicked and the User send his Mail i get following text in my "Schelchtes Druckbild:false". What I want is that instead of true or false it shows me a Text like "Ja" oder "Nein".

Comment: Is there any button which your user press to send the email?

Comment: If there is a button then inside the OnClick method of that button you can do if(cb.isChecked){ String str = "ja"}else{str = "Nein"} and the you can send the string to the intent.

Comment: how do i send the String to the email Intent?? emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,+ "\n Fehler: " + checkBox1.isChecked() doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, checkBox1.getText().toString()+":"+checkBox1.isChecked());
```

Comment: Sorry doesnt work But Thank You all very Much I Like This Forum :) Greets from Germany. Have Anyone an Idea